# Models are not all fitted to the same size of dataset yet I have no missing values among the predictor variables?

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I am trying to run some linear models with lme4 in R studio. I keep running into the same error when I compare the models using the `anova` function. Here is the data set I am working with

```
structure(list(sub = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956"), subject = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21"), event = c(68L, 
56L, 72L, 37L, 71L, 48L), timestamp = c("24-Nov-2020 14:27:09", 
"24-Nov-2020 14:11:17", "24-Nov-2020 14:27:37", "24-Nov-2020 14:09:01", 
"24-Nov-2020 14:27:29", "24-Nov-2020 14:10:16"), profile = c("mean", 
"odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd"), rating = c(4, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 5), rt_ms = c(2053, 2370, 3044, 1568, 1112, 1732), image = c("accordion_1", 
"accordion_3", "apple_01", "apple_03", "asian_01", "asian_02"
), trial = c(7L, 55L, 11L, 36L, 10L, 47L), onset_s = c(542.394, 
418.52, 570.127, 283.328, 563.481, 358.924), profile_rating = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), block = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), sub_num = c(179L, 
154L, 179L, 154L, 179L, 154L), session = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), own_pref = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5), cat1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), cat2 = c(2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), item_num = 1:6, 
    own_pref_nan = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), PE = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), PE_si = c(2, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 2), se_PE = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), pro_PE = c(2, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 2), mean_p = c(3.25957446808511, 2.98297872340426, 
    4.42127659574468, 4.45531914893617, 4.41276595744681, 4.08510638297872
    ), med_p = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'll initially run my two (hierarchical) models which run fine with no errors:

```
pref1_feedback <- lmer(rating ~ profile_rating_new + (1|subject), data=subj_rating_new)
summary(pref1_feedback)
```

```
pref1_fb_own <- lmer(rating ~ profile_rating_new * own_pref + (1|subject), data=subj_rating_new)
summary(pref1_fb_own)
```

However, when I run `anova(pref1_feedback, pref1_fb_own)` I receive the following error:

```
Error in anova.merMod(pref1_feedback, pref1_fb_own) : 
  models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

I have checked to make sure there are an equivalent number of items in both predictor variables and removed all NAs. So I'm rather confused at this point as to why it's flagging me for datasets not being the same size. Moreover, I have used the `anova` function in prior datasets (very similar to this one) without a hitch. If anyone has any clue what is going on here, I would greatly appreciate the insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the data fits fine? When I try and run your models with the data provided it crashes because there is only one level of `subject`

Comment: Is there a way to check if my data fits? I haven't altered the dataset all that much and I did this exact computation previously with a near identical data set (just with less subjects) so I'm not quite sure how this one could be different.

Comment: It would be the most helpful if you can re-create your exact problem with the code and data that you have in the post. I think what is happening has to do with `lmer()` dropping observations for some reason, but I can't be sure if I can't get to the problem your having with the code that you have posted